# Itô differential coincides with classical differential for classically differentiable process

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

While studying Itô calculus, I came across the following question. Suppose we have the canonical $d$-dimensional Wiener process $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$, then for sufficiently smooth $h = h(x,y)$, if we put $Y_t := h(t,B_t)$, the Itô formula
$$Y_t - Y_0 = \int_0^t \partial_xh(t,B_t) + \frac{1}{2} \Delta_y^2h(t,B_t) \, dt + \int_0^t \nabla _yh(t,B_t) \cdot dB_t$$
holds. We can write this in formal "differential" notation:
$$dY_t = \left (\partial_x h(t,B_t) +  \frac{1}{2} \Delta_y^2h(t,B_t) \right) dt + \nabla _yh(t,B_t) \cdot dB_t .$$
Somewhere in my book the process $Z_t := \exp(-\int_0^tf(B_s) \, ds)$ appeared, where $f$ is some smooth function. The author claims that $dZ_t = -fZ_t \, dt$, but meant in the sense of Itô's formula above. This confused me since I was not able to write $Z_t$ as some function of $B_t$ and apply Itô's formula (it is rather a functional of $(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$).

However, $-fZ_t $ is of course the classical derivative of the differentiable function $t\mapsto Z_t$. Is it true that these two notions coincide in this case and if yes where can I find a proof of this fact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that Ito's formula is really only used to handle the fact that $t \rightarrow B_t$ is not differentiable, or even finite variation.  Here, the function we're differentiating is $Z_t := \exp(-F_t)$ where $F_t := \int_0^t f(B_s)ds$ and $t \rightarrow F_t$ *is* differentiable even though $B_t$ is not.  It's similar to the fact that if $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is any integrable function then $F(t):=\int_0^t f(g(s))ds$ is differentiable and $F'(t) = f(g(t))$ no matter what $g$ is, even if $g$ is not differentiable or even continuous!  Here we just have that $g(t) = B_t$, so the same reasoning applies.  Then $dZ_t = -f(B_t)Z_t dt$ just follows from the chain rule.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I am well aware that $Z_t$ is classically differentiable and that its derivative is $-f(B_t) Z_t$. What I am wondering is whether this coincides with the differential interpreted using the Itô formula. I think this is not as obvious since it is still random and depends on $\omega$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure I fully understand the question still, but let me know if this helps.  Since $Z_t$ is differentiable, we can take the derivative pathwise, i.e. $dZ_t = dZ(t,\omega) = -f(B(t,\omega)) Z(t, \omega) dt$.  In terms of integrals, this is saying $Z(t,\omega) - 1 = \int_0^t f(B(s,\omega))Z(s,\omega)ds$.  We are only integrating with respect to finite variation processes, so the integrals are also defined pathwise.  Does that help?

Comment: I think I got it now. My question was basically what function $h(t,Z_t)$ to use in order to apply Itô's formula. But I guess I can just choose $h(t) = Z_t$ without dependence on $B_t$ and the non-deterministic parts disappear.

Comment: Yes, exactly!  If it helps, the fully general statement for Ito's formula (at least in the one-dimensional case) is if $H_t$ is a semi-martingale and $g$ is smooth, then $dg(H_t) = g'(H_t)dH_t + \frac 12 g''(H_t) d\langle H,H \rangle_t$, so another way would be to choose $g(x) = \exp(-x)$ and $H_t = \int_0^t f(B_s)ds$.  We know $dH_t = f(B_t)dt$ because that is just notation for $H_t = \int_0^t f(B_s)ds$.

Comment: Thanks, that formula for semi-martingales is what I looked for.